# How to show italic in vim in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, display, iterm, vi

The beloved [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colour scheme seems to apply an italic face for comments, but when I am using it in `vim` in iTerm2, it does not.

So, everything including comments are displayed in Roman (normal) face. 
Even if I select the Menlo font, which has an italic face I can see in iTerm2's preferences window, the comments are rendered as Roman.

Together with the fact that comments are in light gray, and normal text in (not very bright) white, comments become rather difficult to distinguish from normal text.

To me this is a flaw in the otherwise great color scheme. I did some searching but the advice is old and do not solve the problem. I'm using OS X 10.6 Sierra on a MacBook Air.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to update your `TERMINFO` file.

Thanks to [wincent's video](https://youtu.be/n1cKtZfwOgQ?list=PLwJS-G75vM7kFO-yUkyNphxSIdbi_1NKX&t=17) and his [github pages](https://github.com/wincent/wincent/tree/master/roles/terminfo)
Watch the video and look at his github pages, they're excellent.

I have the following note stored on my HD:

We can have *italics* in the terminal.

This works in iTerm as well as Terminal.

We have to adapt the terminfo database to tell it to display italics.

Create a plain text file which contains the following:

```
xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  use=xterm-256color,
```

Save it as `xterm-256color.terminfo.txt`

Then execute the following command:

```
tic -o ~/.terminfo xterm-256color.terminfo.txt
```

This will create a `~/.terminfo/some_arbitrary_number/` directory, and inside that directory is a `xterm-256color` file.

What it does according to the manpage:

```
       The command tic translates a terminfo file from source format into com-
       piled  format.   The  compiled  format  is  necessary  for use with the
       library routines in ncurses(3X).

       The results are  normally  placed  in  the  system  terminfo  directory
       /usr/share/terminfo.  There are two ways to change this behavior.

       First, you may override the system default by setting the variable TER-
       MINFO in your shell environment to a valid (existing) directory name.

       Secondly, if tic cannot get access to /usr/share/terminfo or your  TER-
       MINFO  directory,  it  looks for the directory $HOME/.terminfo; if that
       directory exists, the entry is placed there.

       Libraries that read terminfo entries are expected to check for  a  TER-
       MINFO  directory first, look at $HOME/.terminfo if TERMINFO is not set,
       and finally look in /usr/share/terminfo.

       -o dir   Write  compiled  entries to given directory.  Overrides the TER-
                MINFO environment variable.
```

So with the given command we are writing a new terminfo entry in the hidden `~/.terminfo` directory. It takes the capabilities of the existing xterm-256color entry (from `/usr/share/terminfo/`) and adds italics mode to it.

To check that the terminal does the right thing:

- with fish:

  ```
  echo (tput sitm)'italics' (tput ritm) (tput smso)'standout'(tput rmso)
  ```
- with bash or zsh:

  ```
  echo `tput sitm`italics`tput ritm` `tput smso`standout`tput rmso`
  ```

I guess at the moment most vim terminal colorschemes don't set italic as a style. To check this do:
`:hi Comment` if the reply contains `cterm=italic` you're done.
If not add `highlight Comment cterm=italic` to your vimrc (**below** setting your colorscheme).

**Addendum for tmux**

tmux uses its own terminfo files, they also need to be updated to use italics.

1. create a `tmux.terminfo.txt` file which contains

`tmux|tmux terminal multiplexer,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  smso=\E[7m, rmso=\E[27m,
  use=screen,`

2. create a `tmux-256color.terminfo.txt` file which contains

`tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  smso=\E[7m, rmso=\E[27m,
  use=screen-256color,`

and run the tic command.

`tic -o ~/.terminfo tmux-256color.terminfo.txt`
and
`tic -o ~/.terminfo tmux.terminfo.txt`

Comment: Wow! After doing these, with the test you gave, "italic" and "standout" both works, but opening a cpp in vim does not render comments italic. Is this Solarized's problem?

Comment: Oh! I notice that MacVim's GUI (i.e. the separate window that prompts) can display italic fonts, but if opened in the terminal (with `mvim -v`), it cannot. Is is normal?

Comment: If you do in vim: `:hi Comment` does it say `cterm=italic`? If not Solarized doesn't set this. You can do this in your vimrc with `highlight Comment cterm=italic`

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! MY COMMENTS ARE ITALIC NOW!!! I will tell the world the good news!!! (I always thought Solarized set this by default)

Comment: In my machine (arch linux), cterm=standout displayed *italics*, and the command above could only display the word *standout* but in italics.

Comment: And there were no ~/.terminfo directory and hence no files in it. What is that **78** directory part though?

Comment: I just tried on a Manjaro (based on arch) VM `echo \`tput sitm\`italics\`tput ritm\` \`tput smso\`standout\`tput rmso\`` and it gave the expected result  (italics & standout) without applying the patch. This is an xfce4-terminal. The 78 directory part is showing up on the 2 Macs I have available, I'm not sure if this is just a Mac thing or more general unix. If you look at wincent's video `~/.terminfo` is a directory where the patched terminfo is stored. Presumably when starting the terminal this file is read, instead of the one in `/usr/share/x/terminfo/xterm-256color`

Comment: improved explanation of command, hopefully removed some confusion about directories existing or not.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work in a tmux session.

Comment: for tmux you also have to update its terminfo entries. See [wincent's files](https://github.com/wincent/wincent/tree/master/roles/terminfo/files) for the correct settings.

Comment: wasn't able to get this working inside tmux on macos without also following https://medium.com/@dubistkomisch/how-to-actually-get-italics-and-true-colour-to-work-in-iterm-tmux-vim-9ebe55ebc2be

Answer (score 0):

In addition to updating my `TERMINFO`, I had to make two other changes.

1. Edit `.vim/colors/solarized.vim` as recommended in [Solarized #120](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/120) to replace lines 137-157 with the following:

   ```
    if has("gui_running") || ( has("unix") && system("tput sitm") == "\033[3m" )
        let s:terminal_italic=1
    else
        let s:terminal_italic=0
    endif
   ```
2. Edit `.vimrc` to add the following lines using `<Ctrl-v><Esc>` to enter the `^[` characters.

   ```
    " Enable italics
    set t_ZH=^[[3m
    set t_ZR=^[[23m
   ```