# What is `tic` and what can I do about it using 100% CPU?

Tags: mojave, cpu

I have a process named `tic` that occasionally shows its ugly face in `htop` or Activity Monitor, consuming around 100% CPU.  I couldn't find any good info on it last time I tried.  What is it for, what would make it suck up my processor cycles, and what can be done about it.

I'm on the latest sub-version of Mojave: 10.14.3 (18D42).

Update: this happened again, and about 80% of the lines displayed by `sudo lsof -p PID` were related in some way to Visual Studio Code.  I don't know if that's a useful clue for anyone about the cause... but I'll put it out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man tic` says:

> tic - the terminfo entry-description compiler

You can use it to enable features in you terminal (like italics) that Apple didn't include in the terminfo database.
See: [How to show italic in vim in iTerm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266333/how-to-show-italic-in-vim-in-iterm2/267261#267261)

`tic` is a one-shot program and should not run in the background.
Open Activity Monitor, select `tic` & do ⌘-I, the first line  says **Parent proces:** followed by a (blue) name which is a link. This tells you what launched `tic`, you can click that link to dive deeper in the launchers (*Parent Proces*)  until you end up on `kernel_task`.

If the Parent process says `launchd` you may have an entry in either

- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

Here there live .plist files which control the running of background processes.

You can use [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to see all such daemons or agents.

Comment: LaunchControl is an awesome utility!  (I'm a paid user, but I also appreciate how much you can do with it before you pay.  I heartily recommend it to anyone reading this!)

Comment: The ancestry goes like this: `tic` → `zsh` → Code → `launchd` → `kernel_task`.  Apparently a VS Code extension is the problem.  Quiting `tic` in Activity Monitor returns things to normal after several minutes...